# Server response time is too long ?Entity FrameWork and C# (code first approach)

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, load-time

Well, I browsed through the answers but none of them could solve the problem. When I hit the url for the first time, it takes very long time to boot up. The server response time is close to 30 sec (waiting time TTFB in chrome developer tool).

The subsequent requests are surprisingly faster. I don't think there's problem with the server side code as all the calls are taking this much time.

I don't think this is related to front end either as those contents are downloaded almost immediately.

Here's the link to my website http://nationposts.com

Comment: any luck @Rahul, I am facing same issue